# A consistent definition of the $dx_i$ in the total differential

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

For a differentiable function $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ on an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ the **total differential** at the point $p \in U$ is typically defined as 
$$
{{\rm {d}}}f(p): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}\quad,\quad{{\rm {d}}}f(p):=\sum _{{i=1}}^{n}{\frac  {\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}}(p)\,{{\rm {d}}}x_{i}.
$$
If $e_1, ..., e_n$ denotes the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then we can define linear forms ${{\rm {d}}}x_i: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by letting ${{\rm {d}}}x_i(x) := \pi_i(x) = x_i$, i.e. we project each vector onto its $i$-th coordinate w.r.t. the standard basis. Then we have ${{\rm {d}}}x_i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$ and so the set ${{\rm {d}}}x_1, ..., {{\rm {d}}}x_n$ is the dual basis. Since $df(p)$ is also an element of the dual space $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{*}$ this explains the above coordinate representation of the total differential.

However, the notation ${{\rm {d}}}x$ suggests (at least to me) that the ${{\rm {d}}}x_i$ are some sort of differential themselves and not just defined into existence as I did above. We cannot derive them via the definition of the total differential, because this would constitute a circular argument.

In my lecture notes we defined the **exterior derivative** of a differential 0-form, i.e. a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, as
$$
{{\rm {d}}}f_{o}: U \to {\bigwedge}^1\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)\quad,\quad x \mapsto (df)(x).
$$
So we map every point in $U$ to the corresponding total differential of $f$ - that is ${{\rm {d}}}f_{o}$ is a differential 1-form. In the same notes my professor goes on and defines the ${{\rm {d}}}x_i$ as the exterior derivative of the $\pi_i$. So this elevates the ${{\rm {d}}}x_i$ to the status of *differential* $1$-forms.

How can all these definitions be made consistent? What is a clean and consistent way to define the ${{\rm {d}}}x_i$? Are they best thought of as linear forms or differential $1$-forms?

Comment: the thing to notice is that the $i^{th}$ projection function $x^i: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ is linear hence it is its own differential (and since you seem to be working in $\Bbb{R}^n$ exclusively, I'm not sure if I should elaborate more on tangent spaces to manifolds etc)

Comment: @peek-a-boo: My initial plan was to understand the definitions w.r.t $\mathbb{R}^n$ first because I thought that this was going to be easier, but If you think that my problems can be explained away with the differential between tangent spaces I'd love to hear it.

Comment: honestly, I think the explanation in $\Bbb{R}^n$ is more confusing because $\Bbb{R}^n$ is often the nicest possible structure you can have: it is a topological space, vector space, group(under addition), a metric space, a Banach space, a Hilbert space, a smooth manifold, a Riemannian manifold etc.... basically, it is the prototypical example of several types of spaces. So sometimes, the simplicity can cause you to overlook what is actually going on/unnecessarily invoke extra structure when it is not needed, and hence lead to more confusion in the long-run.

Comment: Of course, this is not to say that you should forget everything you learnt in $\Bbb{R}^n$. Merely that it is SOMETIMES a good idea to learn the concepts in a more abstract setting where there's less clutter, and then later try to see how these definitions coincide with familiar geometric notions.

Comment: I see. Then I'm going to try to understand it in the context of manifolds I guess... Thanks!

Comment: btw which book/notes are you learning from? Sure I could attempt an answer now, but I'd rather see if I could tailor the answer to be more specific (if I'm familiar with the source)

Comment: Mostly I try to stick to my lecture notes of a real analysis 3 course. However, I would like to get a better understanding of the topic and my lecture notes are restricted to $\mathbb{R}^n$ or submanifolds in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The text I'm using currently is Do Carmo's "Differential Forms and Applications"

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of notation, maybe abuse of notation.

The $dx_i$ (defined in any tangent space $T_p$ of points $p\in{\mathbb R}^n$) are the differentials of the "special" functions
$$x_i:\quad{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R},\qquad x=(x_1,\ldots, x_i,\ldots,x_n)\to x_i\qquad(1\leq i\leq n) ,$$
called $\pi_i$ in your question. These $dx_i$ are $n$ different vectors in $T_p^*$, and in fact form a basis of this $T_p^*$. Doing all the calculations, chain rule, etc., one finds that
$$df(p).X=\sum_{i=1}^n{\partial f\over\partial x_i}(p)\>X_i=\sum_{i=1}^n{\partial f\over\partial x_i}(p)\>dx_i(X)\qquad\forall X\in T_p\ ,$$
so that
$$df(p)=\sum_{i=1}^n{\partial f\over\partial x_i}(p)\>dx_i\ .$$
This is not an equation about "infinitesimals", but about linear maps $T_p\to{\mathbb R}$.